# Is there an API for talking to the kubelet?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubelet

I have been searching around the kubernetes documentation and cannot seem to find any descriptions of communicating with a kubelet on `localhost`.

Is there a way to interrogate the `kubelet` about its status and managed pods for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The kubernetes doesn't have any API client talking to kubelet, but for debugging purpose kubelet starts an internal HTTP server which exposed some endpoints like /metrics, /stats, /cadvisor etc for debugging purpose.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go) is the link for that internal HTTP server code.